# On the equations $(x^n+1)(y^n+1)=z^2+1$ and $(x^n-1)(y^n-1)=z^2+1$

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Note that
$$(1^2+1)(2^2+1)=10=3^2+1\ \ \mbox{and}\ \ (1^4+2^4)(5^4+6^4)=8^4+13^4.$$
Today I tried to find positive integers $x,y,z$ satisfying $(x^4+1)(y^4+1)=z^4+1$ but failed. In view of this situation, I pose the following two questions.

**Question 1.** Let $n>2$ be an integer. Does the equation
$$(x^n+1)(y^n+1)=z^2+1,\ \ \mbox{i.e., }\ \ x^n+y^n+x^ny^n=z^2\tag{1}$$
have positive integer solutions?

*Remark* 1. I have checked $(1)$ for $n=3,4,5$ and $x,y=1,\ldots,3000$, and I have not found any positive integer solution of $(1)$. Fermat ever proved that $x^4+y^4=z^2$ has no positive integer solution.

It is easy to see that
$$(x^2-1)((x+1)^2-1)=(x(x+1)-1)^2-1.$$

**Question 2.** Let $n>1$ be an integer. Does the equation
$$(x^n-1)(y^n-1)=z^2+1,\ \ \mbox{i.e., }\ \ x^ny^n-x^n-y^n=z^2\tag{2}$$
have positive integer solutions?

*Remark* 2. I have checked $(2)$ for $n=2,3,4,5$ and $x,y=1,\ldots,3000$, and I have not found any positive integer solution of $(2)$.

I conjecture that the equation $(1)$ has no positive integer solution for each integer $n>2$, and that the equation $(2)$ has no positive integer solution for each integer $n>1$. It seems not difficult to solve the equation $(2)$ for $n=2$.

Your comments are welcome!

Comment: I also conjecture that for each $n=3,4,5,\ldots$ the equation $(x^n+1)(y^n+1)=z^n+1$ has no positive integer solution.

Comment: I find that $(3^5+1)(12^3+1)=75^3+1$,

Comment: Now I guess that the equation $(x^k+1)(y^m+1)=z^n+1$ with $x,y,z\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, $k,m,n\in\{3,4,5,\ldots\}$ and $k\ge m$ has a unique solution: $(3^5+1)(12^3+1)=75^3+1$.